# Elastic search nest search query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am getting stuck getting while implementing search using elastic search nest.
I have to implement like query with elastic search.
for ex. select * from table where username like **'%abc xyz%'**
As you can see in above sql query I have applied like query with string "abc" space and another string "xyz". Similarly I want this query in elastic search. Can anyone help me to implement such query in elastic search nest?

Below is the query

```
Client.Search<Video>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .OnField("video_parent")
            .Query("0")
        ) && q
        .Match(m => m
            .OnField("video_status")
            .Query(objVideosFilterCriteria.Vide‌​oStatus.ToString())
        ) && q
        .MatchPhrase(ff=>ff
            .OnField("video_title")
            .Query(objVideosF‌​ilterCriteria.Search‌​String)
        ) && q
        .Range(r => r
            .OnField(f => f.video_date)
            .GreaterOrEquals(fromDate)
            .LowerOrEquals(toDate‌​)
        ) 
    )
    .From(objVideosFilterCriteria.PageIndex)
    .Size(objVideosFilt‌​erCriteria.PageSize)
‌​);
```

Above is the query I am using. In this query I am using

```
q.MatchPhrase(ff=>ff
    .OnField("video_title")
    .Query(objVideosF‌​‌​ilterCriteria.Sear‌​ch‌​String)
)
```

for like query. But it doesn't seem to work.
I am using below data set and want to filter data from below list.

```
"hits" : [
  {       
    "_source" : {
      "video_id" : 265006,
      "video_title" : "nunchuk rockin roller II"
    }
  },

  {        
    "_source" : {
      "video_id" : 265013,
      "video_title" : "?Shaggy?????Locks???7??????Alberto E. Interview {407} 967 ~ 8596?"
    }
  },
  {        
    "_source" : {
      "video_id" : 265014,
      "video_title" : "Shakin' Stevens - Kalundborg Rocker"
    }
  },
  {       
    "_source" : {
      "video_id" : 265019, 
      "video_title" : "?Shaggy?????Locks? = 7??????Greg M. Interview {407} 967 ~ 8596?"
    }
  },
  {       
    "_source" : {
      "video_id" : 265023, 
      "video_title" : "?Shaggy?????Locks? = 7??????Jason M. Interview {407} 967 ~ 8596?"
    }    
  }
```

]

For example I would like to search with the keyword "kin rol" in the "video_title" field so with the above data it should fetch one record which exists at first position in above list but in my current query I am getting. nothing.

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: please add it to the question

Comment: please add everything from comments to the question

Comment: Done, Please have a look

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you have a concrete example of a document and a query that you would expect to be a match for the document?

Comment: I have updated my questions and put some data on which I want to perform search with some keyword. Please have a look. Hope you can help me out here. Thanks in advance.